# How to create a new List with unique elements from an old List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list like this:

```
  var list = [
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "subType": ["A1", "A2"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "subType": ["A1"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "subType": ["B1"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "subType": ["B2", "B3"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeC",
      "subType": ["C1"]
    }
  ];
```

How can I create a new List with unique elements from an old List?
This is the new list I want:

```
  newList = [
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "subType": ["A1", "A2"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "subType": ["B1", "B2", "B3"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeC",
      "subType": ["C1"]
    }
  ];
```

---

### EDIT: all the answers work, however, I don't know how to apply them to my real project with the model class

so please help me, this is the full code:

```
class ListModel {
  String type;
  List<String> subType;

  ListModel({this.type, this.subType});
}

void main() {
  List<ListModel> list = [
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subType: ['A1', 'A2']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subType: ['A1']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subType: []),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeB', subType: ['B1']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeB', subType: ['B2', 'B3']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeC', subType: ['C1']),
  ];

  //This is newList I want
  List<ListModel> newList = [
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subType: ['A1', 'A2']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeB', subType: ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeC', subType: ['C1']),
  ];
}
```

Comment: check [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) or [groupListBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extension (you can also use it in a function),

```
extension ListExt on List<Map> {
  bool mergeIfContains(Map element) {
    for (Map item in this) {
      if (item.containsKey("type") && (element["type"] == item["type"])) {
        var subTypes = [...item["subType"], ...element["subType"]];
        item["subType"] = Set.from(subTypes).toList();
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Use `mergeIfContains` extension,

```
var list = [
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "subType": ["A1", "A2"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "subType": ["A1"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "subType": ["B1"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "subType": ["B2", "B3"]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeC",
      "subType": ["C1"]
    }
  ];

  var dt = <Map>[];
  list.forEach((element) {
    if (!dt.mergeIfContains(element)) {
      dt.add(element);
    }
  });
  //TODO: dt is what you need
  print(dt);
```

For data model,

```
class ListModel {
  final String type;
  final List<String> subTypes;

  ListModel({this.type, this.subTypes});

  @override
  String toString() => type;

  //This is very important, it replaces default equality check
  @override
  bool operator ==(other) => this.type == other.type;

  @override
  int get hashCode => super.hashCode;
}
```

Now you can use the existing list method i.e. `contains`,

```
var data = [
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subTypes: ['A1', 'A2']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subTypes: ['A1']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subTypes: []),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeB', subTypes: ['B1']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeB', subTypes: ['B2', 'B3']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeC', subTypes: ['C1']),
  ];

  var dt = <ListModel>[];
  data.forEach((element) {
    if (dt.contains(element)) {
      var item = dt.firstWhere((e) => e == element);
      var subTypes = [...item.subTypes, ...element.subTypes];
      item.subTypes.clear();
      item.subTypes.addAll(Set.from(subTypes));
    } else {
      dt.add(element);
    }
  });
  //TODO: dt is what you need
  print(dt);
```

Just to test the result, you can replace `toString()` in `ListModel` with,

```
@override
String toString() => "$type => $subTypes";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I updated the question, Pls help me  more xD

Comment: @Kel I've updated the answer for implementation with data models. You need not create an extension if you override the equality operator in the data model.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you

create a function to merge list items

I also added `toString()` to ListModel to represent it as a String.

```
class ListModel {
  String type;
  List<String> subType;

  ListModel({this.type, this.subType});

  @override
  String toString() => 'ListModel(type: $type, subType: $subType)';
}

void main() {
  List<ListModel> list = [
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subType: ['A1', 'A2']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subType: ['A1']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeA', subType: []),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeB', subType: ['B1']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeB', subType: ['B2', 'B3']),
    ListModel(type: 'TypeC', subType: ['C1']),
  ];
  print(mergeListItems(list));
}

List<ListModel> mergeListItems(List<ListModel> list) {
  final newList = <ListModel>[];
  for (final model in list) {
    var index = newList.indexWhere((element) => element.type == model.type);
    if (index == -1) {
      newList.add(model);
      index = newList.length - 1;
    }
    for (final subType in model.subType) {
      final subtypeIndex =
          newList[index].subType.indexWhere((t) => t == subType);
      if (subtypeIndex == -1) newList[index].subType.add(subType);
    }
  }
  return newList;
}
```

Result

```
[ListModel(type: TypeA, subType: [A1, A2]), ListModel(type: TypeB, subType: [B1, B2, B3]), ListModel(type: TypeC, subType: [C1])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the question, pls help me more :)

Comment: @Kel I updated my answer, check it and accept it if it was helpful.